# How can I use inbuilt validation of MVC3 in partial views containing Ajax.beginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, partial-views, ajax.beginform

I have four partial views on my page. And on each partial view I am using AJAX.BeginForm. In each partial view I have one submit button and on click of that button I want to validate the controls of that partial view only. I have included inbuilt js files **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** and **jquery.validate.min.js** in my master page i.e. layout.cshtml

But if I use AJAX.BeginForm in my partial view then it does not validate the controls because those js files are not included in this ajax form.

One way is that I include all those js files in each Partial view but I do not want to take this approach because it is making my page very heavy.

Is their any other way that I can validate my controls without including all js files in all partial views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Re-attach the validators after the partial view is loaded. Like this:

```
$(function (){
    $('yourSelector').removeData("validator");
    $('yourSelector').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('yourSelector');
});
```

*yourSelector* can be the form.

Comment: this will work but it will remove validation from any other forms that are on the page

Comment: Jason, passing the right selector should not affect other forms on the page.